Sent Mail Signature Field Disabled Issue
When sending a document using the PandaDoc API and specifying the signature field as required and not disabled, recipients receive the document via email, but the signature field appears disabled for them. This prevents them from signing the document, despite the correct configuration in the API request.
Details:
1. The document is created using the PandaDoc API, and the signature field is included in the sending parameters with the required and disabled properties set to false.
2. Recipients receive the email with the document attached, but the signature field appears disabled when they try to sign it.
3. The document is in draft status when sent, and recipients should have the necessary permissions to interact with the signature field.
How can I actually enable the signature field for the recipient(s)?
var sendingParams = new
{
    subject = "Your Agreement from PandaDoc",
    message = "Please review and sign the attached agreement.",
    silent = false, // Set to true if you don't want to send email notifications
    forwarding_settings = new
    {
        forwarding_allowed = true,
        forwarding_with_reassigning_allowed = true
    },
    recipients = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            email = recipientEmail,
            role = "Client",
            fields = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    type = "signature", // Specify field type as "signature"
                    required = true, // Make the signature field required
                    disabled = false // Ensure that the signature field is not disabled
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

